# Не работает bootstrap hover image в адаптиве

Tags: bootstrap, hover

Добрый день. Надеюсь на подсказку, т.к. не могу понять, в чем проблема. Суть: использую один из hover эффектов с этого источника: https://miketricking.github.io/dist/

Проблема заключается в том, что, в адаптиве, когда картинки становятся в 2 или 1 колонку, пропадает hover эффект.

Сайт, на котором проблема - http://devkeyz.crabdance.com , раздел "Наши работы"

html
                
                     
                        
                        
                            Ремонт платформы

Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.

```
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
                 <div class="hovereffect">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/work3.png" alt="">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <span>Установка гидроцилинрда</span>
                                <p>
                                Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
                                </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
                 <div class="hovereffect">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/work4.png" alt="">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <span>Установка системы BDF</span>
                                <p>
                                Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
                                </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
                 <div class="hovereffect">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/work1.png" alt="">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <span>Ремонт платформы</span>
                                <p>
                                Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
                                </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
                 <div class="hovereffect">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/work2.png" alt="">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <span>Ремонт платформы</span>
                                <p>
                                Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
                                </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
                 <div class="hovereffect">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/work3.png" alt="">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <span>Ремонт платформы</span>
                                <p>
                                Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
                                </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 portfolio-item">
                 <div class="hovereffect">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/work4.png" alt="">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <span>Ремонт платформы</span>
                                <p>
                                Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
                                </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

SASS

```
.portfolio-item
    margin: 15px 0px
    .hovereffect
        width: 100%
        height: auto
        overflow: hidden
        position: relative
        text-align: center
        cursor: default
        float: left
        .overlay
            position: absolute
            overflow: hidden
            width: 80%
            height: 80%
            left: 10%
            top: 10%
            border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF
            border-top: 1px solid #FFF
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s
            transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s
            -webkit-transform: scale(0,1)
            -ms-transform: scale(0,1)
            transform: scale(0,1)
    &:hover .overlay
        opacity: 1
        filter: alpha(opacity=100)
        -webkit-transform: scale(1)
        -ms-transform: scale(1)
        transform: scale(1)
        img
            display: block
            position: relative
            -webkit-transition: all 0.35s
            transition: all 0.35s
    &:hover img
        filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.6" /></feComponentTransfer></filter></svg>#filter')
        filter: brightness(0.3)
        -webkit-filter: brightness(0.3)
        transition: 0.3s
    span
        text-transform: uppercase
        font-weight: bold
        text-align: center
        position: relative
        font-size: 17px
        background-color: transparent
        color: #FFF
        padding: 1em 0
        opacity: 0
        filter: alpha(opacity=0)
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s
        transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0)
        transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0)
    p
        color: #FFF
        opacity: 0
        filter: alpha(opacity=0)
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s
        transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0)
        transform: translate3d(0,100%,0)
    &:hover p, :hover span
        opacity: 1
        filter: alpha(opacity=100)
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Формат записи `<img></img>` - не допустим. Используй `<img />` либо просто `<img>`
2. Для поиска ошибок в html используй [html-валидатор](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)
3. Используй панель инструментов разработчика <kbd>F12</kbd>. Для поиска перекрывающихся элементов используй инструмент picker <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + C</kbd>. На картинке видно что я задал фон блоку "Изготовление кузовов" и он перекрывает элементы портфолио выше, поэтому на них не срабатывает наведение.
4. Не создавай много ненужных DOM-вложеностей, ты ускоришь процесс отрисовки страницы. Блоки с шириной в 12 колонок можно просто вынести из row (изготовление кузовов)

[image: перекрывающиеся элементы]

Comment: Спасибо, вынес в отдельный .row блок с текстом, теперь hover срабатывает. Подскажите пожалуйста, еще такой вопрос. У меня, при тестировании в Chrome, когда выбираю отображать как на моб устройстве, появляется небольшая горизонтальная прокрутка, такое чувство, что какой-то элемент создает паддинг и выпирает за пределы бутстрап сетки. Я не практикую вёрстку, мой условно говоря пилотный проект, сделал за сутки знакомуму на коленке, сам отрисовал, сам сверстал, вот теперь пытаюсь определить баги, попутно изучая новое. Теги обязательно поправлю, точнее они уже исправлены на локальном.

Comment: Причин для того чтобы появился горизонтальный скролл может быть очень много. Для начала проверьте чтобы не было `col` без родительского `row`. Также советую использовать [указатель](http://prntscr.com/e9xlgd), нажмите его, и водите им по подозрительным элементам страницы - он будет показывать размеры каждого элемента в px. Также можно написать небольшой скрипт на jquery который будет перебирать все элементы на странице и проверять чтобы их ширина не превышала ширину окна. Думаю вы сможете без проблем это сделать самостоятельно 

Comment: Благодарю в очередной раз за советы и подсказки. У меня <nav> содержал 'row', но отсутствовал для него 'container'. Точно так же, кое где отсутствовал 'row' для 'col' и внизу в футере не стоял 'class="img-responsive"' у логотипа.

Answer (score 0):

нет открывающего тега `<i>`

```
<li><a href="#services">Услуги</i></a></li>
```

тегу `<img>` закрывающий тег не нужен

```
<a href="#"><img src="/img/zernovoz.png"></img></a>
```

Comment: Это я уже прогнал через w3 и поправил на локалке, но вопрос не в этому, ошибки в коде я вижу, я скинул другой кусок кода, блок "Наши работы", и при ресайзинге, когда в ряд получается 2 или 1 картинка, ховер не срабатывает почему-то.

Comment: Изготовление кузовов оберните в отдельный класс row и всё заработает